# Where to give filepath in opencsv project

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I am new to java and I need to read a csv file using opencsv project. Please guide me that in which file and where I have to put the code:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
    String [] nextLine;
    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
        System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");
    }
```

Many Thanks,
Regards,
Faisal

Comment: Do you have some existing project into which you are integrating this? If so, put the code there. otherwise, write a small java class of your own and put the code there.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "youfile.csv" is at the root of your project.
The variable "nextLine" does not need to be an array.

```
String nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    System.out.println(nextLine);
}
```

This will printout all off the lines because the print statement is in the loop.